# Data is automatically disappearing when uploaded to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When sending the data to a Database in Firebase, for some reason the data is disappearing automatically. Here's the video showing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pWCNx7MsiY

I've been trying to solve this problem for several days, but it's not very difficult. Someone else might have the same problem.

Main code of MainActivity.class:

```
alreadyRegistered = findViewById(R.id.alreadyRegistered);
alreadyRegistered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String colorField = color.getText().toString();
        final String birthdateField = (birthdate.getText().toString());
        final String genderInString = genderField.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String identifierString = identifier.getText().toString().trim();
        String identifierStringInHash = encryptInMD5(identifierString);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(identifierStringInHash);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(identifierStringInHash);

                        String name = "Testing";
                        String email = "testingtesting@gmail.com";
                        String telephone = "55555555555";

                        HashMap<String, String> sendDataToDataBase = new HashMap<>();
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Name", name);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Email", email);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Identifier", identifierStringInHash);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Telephone", telephone);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Color1", colorField);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Birthdate", birthdateField);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Gender", genderInString);

                        try {
                            root .child(identifierStringInHash).setValue(sendDataToDataBase);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.getMessage();
                        }

                        Intent senderIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("name", name);
                        parameters.putString("email", email);
                        parameters.putString("color1", colorField);
                        parameters.putString("birthdate", birthdateField);
                        parameters.putString("gender", genderInString);
                        parameters.putString("identifierStringInHash", identifierStringInHash);
                        parameters.putString("telephone", telephone);
                        senderIntent.putExtras(parameters);
                        startActivity(senderIntent);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), identifierStringInHash, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

MainActivity2.class code:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Button alreadyRegistered;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference root = database.getReference().child("Users");
    DatabaseReference reference;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList_father;

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter_father;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList_Brazil;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList_UnitedStates;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList_Germany;

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter_child;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cadastrodeusuario2);

        Spinner spinner_color = findViewById(R.id.spinnerColor);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.color, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_color.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner_color.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner countryField = findViewById(R.id.spinner_country);

        Spinner city_spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_city);

        arrayList_father = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList_father.add("Brazil");
        arrayList_father.add("United States");
        arrayList_father.add("Germany");

        arrayAdapter_father = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_father);

        countryField.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_father);

        arrayList_Brazil = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList_Brazil.add("São Paulo");
        arrayList_Brazil.add("Rio de Janeiro");
        arrayList_Brazil.add("Brasília");

        arrayList_UnitedStates = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList_UnitedStates.add("New York");
        arrayList_UnitedStates.add("San Francisco");
        arrayList_UnitedStates.add("Whashington");

        arrayList_Germany = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList_Germany.add("Berlin");
        arrayList_Germany.add("Dortmund");
        arrayList_Germany.add("Stuttgart");

        countryField.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    arrayAdapter_child = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_Brazil);
                }
                if (position == 1) {
                    arrayAdapter_child = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_UnitedStates);
                }
                if (position == 2) {
                    arrayAdapter_child = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_Germany);
                }
                city_spinner.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) arrayAdapter_child);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        alreadyRegistered = findViewById(R.id.alreadyRegistered2);
        alreadyRegistered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String color2 = spinner_color.getSelectedItem().toString();
                final String country = countryField.getSelectedItem().toString();
                final String city = city_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Intent receiverIntent = getIntent();
                Bundle receiverBundle = receiverIntent.getExtras();
                String name = receiverBundle.getString("name");
                String email = receiverBundle.getString("email");
                String color1 = receiverBundle.getString("color1");
                String birthdate = receiverBundle.getString("birthdate");
                String gender = receiverBundle.getString("gender");
                String identifierStringInHash = receiverBundle.getString("identifierStringInHash");
                String telephone = receiverIntent.getStringExtra("telephone");

                reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        HashMap<String, String> sendDataToDataBase = new HashMap<>();
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Name", name);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Email", email);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Identifier", identifierStringInHash);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Telephone", telephone);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Color1", color1);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Birthdate", birthdate);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Gender", gender);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("City", city);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Color2", color2);
                        sendDataToDataBase.put("Country", country);

                        try {
                            root.child(identifierStringInHash).setValue(sendDataToDataBase);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.getMessage();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Spinner spinner_city = findViewById(R.id.spinner_city);
        if (position == 0)
            arrayAdapter_child = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_Brazil);

        if (position == 1) {
            arrayAdapter_child = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_UnitedStates);
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            arrayAdapter_child = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList_Germany);
        }

        spinner_city.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) arrayAdapter_child);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Please, anybody can help? I really can't fix this error myself.
For some reason, the value sent to Firebase later becomes null. That's why the data in Firebase is disappearing.
But why is the sent data turning into null?

Answer (score 1):

The only place I see writing in your code is:

```
root.child(identifierStringInHash).setValue(sendDataToDataBase);
```

This writes the data in `sendDataToDataBase` to the `identifierStringInHash` path in the database, replacing any existing data at that path.

---

If you want to **merge** the data in `sendDataToDataBase` with the existing data in `identifierStringInHash`, you can call `updateChildren()`:

```
root.child(identifierStringInHash).updateChildren(sendDataToDataBase);
```

With `updateChildren` any property that exists in `sendDataToDataBase` overwrites the existing value of that property under `identifierStringInHash`. But any new properties will be added to `identifierStringInHash`, and any properties that you don't specify will be left unmodified in `identifierStringInHash`.

---

If you instead want to keep a list of each submission, you'll want to cal `push()`:

```
root.child(identifierStringInHash).push().setValue(sendDataToDataBase);
```

The `push()` call generates a new child node under `identifierStringInHash` and writes the data there. Each time you call `push().setValue(...)` it adds a new child node to the list.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Frank.

Even writing the code: root.child(identifierStringInHash).updateChildren(sendDataToDataBase);

It continues showing the same problem.

If writing the code: root.child(identifierStringInHash).push().setValue(sendDataToDataBase); 
Then the Firebase creates another child, and then also automatically disappear.

Please, would you mind to install this code in your Android Studio and test yourself?

I have been suffering this problem in Firebase for several days, and all attempts, despite being fully valid, are failing to resolve the problem.

Comment: I know how the API works, so that's not the problem. What isn't clear is what output you want/expect, which is why I explained the options in my answer. If that doesn't help you solve the problem, edit your question to show (preferably in JSON as text, no videos or screenshots) what you *do* get in the database, and what you'd like to get instead.

Comment: Hello Frank. Thank you very much again for your answer. 
What I want is simply all data be stored in the Firebase, which it is not happening, as shown in the YouTube video: : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pWCNx7MsiY

You can see that through video, some data sent are being automatically "disappeared", after very some short time. 

It's probably better to show the error happening through a video, than in JSON, right? :)

You can see on this video, that the datas called city, color2 and country are sent in the Firebase, but after a very short time, these datas automatically disappears.

Comment: I watched the video, and it isn't clear to me, which is why I asked for the JSON. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯